# Curve fit with a piecewise function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython

As the title suggests, I am trying to do a curve fit with a piecewise function. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sio

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 3, 4, 11, 18, 27])

def f(x, a):
    if x <= 2:
        return x + a
    elif x >= 3:
        return x**2 + a

sio.curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

Now, this returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous
```

By adding a print function, I figured out that this is because the 'x' value passed in to the function 'f' is the numpy array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I was wondering if there is a workaround to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is more specifically that you are asking if `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] < 2` is True. The way numpy interprets this is to return an array `[True, True, False, False, False ]`. Python doesn't know how to deal with this. I think you think your code does something different than what you want it to do. What do you want f(x,a) to do?

Comment: The goal of f would be to look at each element of the array, so what tom10 suggested is to go through the array and apply f to each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the kind of problem where you can use np.boolean arrays to your advantage.  If you have a large array of data, it is much more efficient than looping over the array, and allows you to use arbitrary expressions as your if/else conditions.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sio

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 3, 4, 11, 18, 27])

def f(x, a):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    y += (x + a) * (x <= 2)
    y += (x ** 2 + a) * (x >= 3)
    return y

sio.curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

where x <= 2 =

```
[True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

which can be used in a numpy expression as:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The overall problem is that you've written `f` as for scalars, but `x` and `a` are numpy arrays.  This is the case both for your `if` line, and also the `return`s within the `if` statements.

A solution most similar to your code would be to do:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sio

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 3, 4, 11, 18, 27])

def f(x, a):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i, xi in enumerate(x): 
        if xi <= 2:
            y[i] =  xi + a
        elif xi >= 3:
            y[i] =  xi**2 + a
    return y

sio.curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

A more vectorized definition of `f` would be:

```
def f(x, a):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    y[:3] += a
    y[3:] = x[3:]**2 + a
    return y
```

Comment: I see, thanks. For your first solution, it appears that you are just setting y to a different value each time instead of appending it to the array, but I get the idea.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Thanks. It's fixed now.  (Overall, though, I haven't tested this to make sure it all makes sense within the `curve_fit`, etc.  I just wanted to outline the basic issues and a few possible solutions.  Certainly, more code is needed, but this answers your immediate question.)