# Python, scipy - How to fit a curve using a piecewise function with a conditional parameter that also needs to be calculated?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, conditional-statements

As the title suggests, I'm trying to fit a piecewise equation to a large data set. The equations I would like to fit to my data are as follows:

y(x) = b, when x < c

else:

y(x)  = b + exp(a(x-c)) - 1, when x >= c

There are multiple answers to how such an issue can be addressed, but as a Python beginner I can't figure out how to apply them to my problem:
[Curve fit with a piecewise function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272191/curve-fit-with-a-piecewise-function)
[Conditional curve fit with scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892502/conditional-curve-fit-with-scipy)

The problem is that all variables (a,b and c) have to be calculated by the fitting algorithm.

Thank you for your help!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Reduced Dataset
y = np.array([23.032, 21.765, 20.525, 21.856, 21.592, 20.754, 20.345, 20.534,
       23.502, 21.725, 20.126, 21.381, 20.217, 21.553, 21.176, 20.976,
       20.723, 20.401, 22.898, 22.02 , 21.09 , 22.543, 22.584, 22.799,
       20.623, 20.529, 20.921, 22.505, 22.793, 20.845, 20.584, 22.026,
       20.621, 23.316, 22.748, 20.253, 21.218, 23.422, 23.79 , 21.371,
       24.318, 22.484, 24.775, 23.773, 25.623, 23.204, 25.729, 26.861,
       27.268, 27.436, 29.471, 31.836, 34.034, 34.057, 35.674, 41.512,
       48.249])

x = np.array([3756., 3759., 3762., 3765., 3768., 3771., 3774., 3777., 3780.,
       3783., 3786., 3789., 3792., 3795., 3798., 3801., 3804., 3807.,
       3810., 3813., 3816., 3819., 3822., 3825., 3828., 3831., 3834.,
       3837., 3840., 3843., 3846., 3849., 3852., 3855., 3858., 3861.,
       3864., 3867., 3870., 3873., 3876., 3879., 3882., 3885., 3888.,
       3891., 3894., 3897., 3900., 3903., 3906., 3909., 3912., 3915.,
       3918., 3921., 3924.])

# Simple exponential function without conditions (works so far)
def exponential_fit(x,a,b,c):
    return b + np.exp(a*(x-c)) 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential_fit, x, y, p0 = [0.1, 20,3800])

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, exponential_fit(x, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your function to something like

```py
def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    if x >= c:
        return b + np.exp(a*(x-c))-1
    else:
        return b
```

**Edit**: As chaosink pointed out in the comments, this approach no longer works as the the above function assumes that `x` is a scalar. However, `curve_fit` evaluates the function for array-like `x`. Consequently, one should use vectorised operations instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74773650/how-can-i-use-curve-fit-for-functions-that-involve-case-splitting/74774463#74774463) for more details. To do so, one can either use

```py
def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    return np.where(x >= c, b + np.exp(a*(x-c))-1, b)
```

or chaosink's suggestion in the comments:

```py
def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    mask = (x >= c)
    return mask * (b + np.exp(a*(x-c)) - 1) + ~mask * b
```

Both give:

[image]

Comment: Seems `(x>=c) * (b + np.exp(a*(x-c))-1) + (x<c) * b` instead of `if` statement should be used. However, this still doesn't converge.

Comment: @chaosink Thanks for your comment. You're right of course. Seems like curve_fit used to use a simple for-loop to evaluate the function with the x data back then. I edited the answer accordingly. However, for me it still converges.