# How can I use curve_fit for functions that involve case-splitting?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to use `curve_fit` for functions that involve case-splitting.
However python throws Error.

Does `curve_fit` not support such a function ? Or is there is any problem at function definition ?

Example)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def slope_devided_by_cases(x,a,b):
    if x < 4:
        return a*x + b
    else:
        return 4*a + b

data_x =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  # x
data_y  = [45,46,42,36,27,23,21,13,11]  # y
coef, cov = curve_fit(slope_devided_by_cases, data_x, data_y)
```

Error)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Lisa~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1516/1012358816.py in <module>
     10 data_x =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  # x
     11 data_y  = [45,46,42,36,27,23,21,13,11]  # y
---> 12 coef, cov = curve_fit(slope_devided_by_cases, data_x, data_y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    787         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    788         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 789         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    790         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    791         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    408     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    409         args = (args,)
--> 410     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    411     m = shape[0]
    412 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    483     if transform is None:
    484         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 485             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    486     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    487         def func_wrapped(params):

C:\Users\Lisa~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1516/1012358816.py in slope_devided_by_cases(x, a, b)
      3 
      4 def slope_devided_by_cases(x,a,b):
----> 5     if x < 4:
      6         return a*x + b
      7     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want to use `curve_fit` for functions that involve case-splitting such as above example.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `if x<a:` when `x` is an array like `data_x`.  `fit` is going to call your function like `slope_devided_by_cases(data_x,1,1)` and then try to compare that result with `data_y`.  Look at `data_x<1`.  What does that mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `x < 4` is not a boolean scalar value because `curve_fit` will evaluate your function with an np.ndarray `x` (your given x data points), not a scalar value. Consequently, `x < 4` will give you an array of boolean values.

That said, you could rewrite your function by using NumPy's vectorized operations:

```py
def slope_devided_by_cases(x,a,b):
    return (x < 4) * (a*x + b) + (x >= 4) * (4*a+b)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as a vectorized alternative to your if-else approach:

```py
def slope_devided_by_cases(x,a,b):
    return np.where(x < 4, a*x + b, 4+a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting approach could be using the [`piecewise`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) function from numpy.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


def f(x, a, b):
    return np.piecewise(
        x, [x < 4, x >= 4], [lambda x_: a * x_ + b, lambda x_: 4 * a + b]
    )


data_x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
data_y = np.array([45, 46, 42, 36, 27, 23, 21, 13, 11])
coeff, cov = curve_fit(f, data_x, data_y)

y_fit = f(data_x, *coeff)
plt.plot(data_x, data_y, "o")
plt.plot(data_x, y_fit, "-")
plt.show()
```

Here is the result of the optimization (maybe a better model could be chosen, but I don't know all the details of the problem at hand and I didn't even specify any initial value since this question is more about making the code work).
[image]